# Async function returned Undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js, undefined, es6-promise

I am calling an async function that retrieves a single row from a table, then increments a value in the row.

I created an async function to perform this as I will need to perform this action a few times in my program.

The issue I have is that function works correctly (gets the value and increments the number) but the calling function receives 'undefined' as the returned results.

I will admit that I am new to promises and am only starting to get a handle on them.

Here is the code that gets the value and increments the counter.

```
    getCallNumber = async (officeId) => {
      const sqlGet = `SELECT CALL_YEAR, CALL_NUM FROM Numbers WHERE OFFICE_ID = '${officeId}';`;
      const sqlPut = `UPDATE Numbers SET CALL_NUM = CALL_NUM + 1 WHERE OFFICE_ID = '${officeId}';`;
      await models.sequelize.transaction(async transaction => {
        try {
          const num = await models.sequelize.query(sqlGet, { type: models.Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT, transaction, raw: true },)
          await models.sequelize.query(sqlPut, { type: models.Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE, transaction, raw: true },)
          console.log("Call Number retrieved and incremented");
          console.log(num);
          return num;
        } catch (error) {
          transaction.rollback();
          console.error(error);
          throw `TRANSACTION_ERROR`;
        }
      });
    }
```

I can see the output says:

```
    Call Number retrieved and incremented
    [ { CALL_YEAR: 20, CALL_NUM: 7189 } ]
```

The calling function looks like this:

```
getCallNumber(calldata.OFFICE_ID).then((callnum) => {
  console.log(callnum);
```

The output for that is:

```
    undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not returning from the function. Should be `return models.sequelize.transaction(...)`

Comment: Do you mean adding another .then to the models.sequelize.transation?
I added:
 }).then((num) => {
    return num;
 });
I guessed it would capture the inside return and I would then return it again.
Cause, if so, it didn't work either.

Comment: No I literally mean you need to return from the `getCallNumber ` function. Currently your function is equivalent to `await models....; return undefined;`